# How to wrap and execute a lisp s-expression by another s-expression?

Tags: macros, common-lisp

I tried to wrap a lisp expression by another lisp expression. I guess, a macro should do it, but I don't get the trick. Can someone help me, who knows how to do it?

My actual aim is to write a macro which wraps a batch of `with-open-file` expressions around  some  macro-body code.

(I want to write a script/program, which opens one or two input files, process them line by line, but also outputs the processing result in several different independent output files. For that I would love to have the `with-open-file` macro calls piled up around the code which processes and writes to the independent output files - all opened for the macro-body code).

Since the `with-open-file` requires a symbol (handler) for the input or output stream and the path variable to the output (or input) file, and some additional information (direction of the file etc.), I want to put them into lists.

```
;; Output file-paths:
(defparameter *paths* '("~/out1.lisp" "~/out2.lisp" "~/out3.lisp"))

;; stream handlers (symbols for the output streams)
(defparameter *handlers* '(out1 out2 out3))

;; code which I would love to execute in the body
(print "something1" out1)
(print "something2" out2)
(print "something3" out3)
```

How I would love the macro to be called:

```
(with-open-files (*handlers* *paths* '(:direction :output :if-exists :append))
  ;; the third macro argument should be what should be passed to the
  ;; individual `with-open-file` calls
  ;; and it might be without `quote`-ing or with `quote`-ing
  ;; - is there by the way a good-practice for such cases? -
  ;; - is it recommended to have `quote`-ing? Or how would you do that? -
  ;; and then follows the code which should be in the macro body:
  (print "something1" out1)
  (print "something2" out2)
  (print "something3" out3))
```

To what the macro call should expand:

```
(with-open-file (out1 "~/out1.lisp" :direction :output :if-exists :append)
  (with-open-file (out2 "~/out2.lisp" :direction :output :if-exists :append)
    (with-open-file (out3 "~/out3.lisp" :direction :output :if-exists :append)
      (print "something1" out1)
      (print "something2" out2)
      (print "something3" out3))))
```

As one step, I thought I have to make an s-expression wrap another s-expression.

My first question was: **How to wrap an s-expression by another s-expression?** But I just couldn't manage it already at this point.
All I could do was to write a function which just spills out an un-executed expression. How to write a macro which does the same but also executes the code after expanding it in this way?

```
(defun wrap (s-expr-1 s-expr-2)
  (append s-expr-1 (list s-expr-2)))

(wrap '(func1 arg1) '(func2 arg2))
;; => (FUNC1 ARG1 (FUNC2 ARG2))

(wrap '(with-open-files (out1 "~/out1.lisp" :direction :output :if-exists :append))
  '(with-open-files (out2 "~/out2.lisp" :direction :output :if-exists :append) 
      (print "something1" out1)
      (print "something2" out2)
      (print "something3" out3)))
```

Which gives:

```
(WITH-OPEN-FILES (OUT1 "~/out1.lisp" :DIRECTION :OUTPUT :IF-EXISTS :APPEND)
 (WITH-OPEN-FILES (OUT2 "~/out2.lisp" :DIRECTION :OUTPUT :IF-EXISTS :APPEND)
  (PRINT "something1" OUT1) 
  (PRINT "something2" OUT2)
  (PRINT "something3" OUT3)))
```

In this way, applying `wrap` function successively, looping over the input-lists, I could build the code maybe ...

However, these functions would generate only code but don't execute it.
And I would be forced at the end to use the `eval` function to evaluate the built code ... (But somehow I know this shouldn't be done like this. And I just didn't really understood how to write macros which do such things ... Actually, macros are there for solving exactly such problems ... )

With the execution, I just came into big trouble. And since one cannot call `funcall` or `apply` on macros (instead of function-names) I don't see an obvious solution. Did someone had experience with such kind of situations?

And when accomplished wrapping an s-expression in a macro by another s-expression *and let it be evaluated*, the next question would be, how to process the list to let the code to expand to the desired code and then be evaluated? I just tried hours and didn't came far.

I need help from someone who has experience to write such kind of macros ...

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Please note that in Lisp, "handler" is normally a *function*, not a symbol. Your naming is confusing.

## Static

If you are generating *code*, you should use *macros*, not functions.
This assumes that you know at *compile time* what files and stream
variable you will use:

The simplest approach is to use recursion:

```
(defmacro with-open-files ((streams file-names &rest options &key &allow-other-keys) &body body)
  (if (and streams file-names)
      `(with-open-file (,(pop streams) ,(pop file-names) ,@options)
         (with-open-files (,streams ,file-names ,@options)
           ,@body))
      `(progn ,@body)))
```

Test:

```
(macroexpand-1
 '(with-open-files ((a b c) ("f" "g" "h") :direction :output :if-exists :supersede)
   (print "a" a)
   (print "b" b)
   (print "c" c)))
==>
(WITH-OPEN-FILE (A "f" :DIRECTION :OUTPUT :IF-EXISTS :SUPERSEDE)
  (WITH-OPEN-FILES ((B C) ("g" "h") :DIRECTION :OUTPUT :IF-EXISTS :SUPERSEDE)
    (PRINT "a" A) (PRINT "b" B) (PRINT "c" C)))

(macroexpand-1
 '(with-open-files ((a) ("f") :direction :output :if-exists :supersede)
   (print "a" a)))
==>
(WITH-OPEN-FILE (A "f" :DIRECTION :OUTPUT :IF-EXISTS :SUPERSEDE)
  (WITH-OPEN-FILES (NIL NIL :DIRECTION :OUTPUT :IF-EXISTS :SUPERSEDE)
    (PRINT "a" A)))

(macroexpand-1
 '(with-open-files (nil nil :direction :output :if-exists :supersede)
   (print nil)))
==>
(PROGN (PRINT NIL))
```

## Dynamic

If you do not know at compile time what the streams and files are, e.g.,
they are stored in the `*handler*` variable, you *cannot* use the simple
macro above - you will have to roll your own using
[`progv`](http://clhs.lisp.se/Body/s_progv.htm) for binding and
[`gensym`](http://clhs.lisp.se/Body/f_gensym.htm) to avoid variable
capture. Note how the `let` inside backtick avoids multiple
evaluation (i.e., arguments `streams`, `file-names` and `options` are to
be evaluated *once*, not multiple times):

```
(defmacro with-open-files-d ((streams file-names &rest options &key &allow-other-keys) &body body)
  (let ((sv (gensym "STREAM-VARIABLES-"))
        (so (gensym "STREAM-OBJECTS-"))
        (ab (gensym "ABORT-"))
        (op (gensym "OPTIONS-")))
    `(let* ((,sv ,streams)
            (,ab t)
            (,op (list ,@options))
            (,so (mapcar (lambda (fn) (apply #'open fn ,op)) ,file-names)))
       (progv ,sv ,so
         (unwind-protect (multiple-value-prog1 (progn ,@body) (setq ,ab nil))
           (dolist (s ,so)
             (when s
               (close s :abort ,ab))))))))

(macroexpand-1
 '(with-open-files-d ('(a b c) '("f" "g" "h")  :direction :output :if-exists :supersede)
   (print "a" a)
   (print "b" b)
   (print "c" c)))
==>
(LET* ((#:STREAM-VARIABLES-372 '(A B C))
       (#:ABORT-374 T)
       (#:OPTIONS-375 (LIST :DIRECTION :OUTPUT :IF-EXISTS :SUPERSEDE))
       (#:STREAM-OBJECTS-373
        (MAPCAR (LAMBDA (FN) (APPLY #'OPEN FN #:OPTIONS-375)) '("f" "g" "h"))))
  (PROGV
      #:STREAM-VARIABLES-372
      #:STREAM-OBJECTS-373
    (UNWIND-PROTECT
        (MULTIPLE-VALUE-PROG1 (PROGN (PRINT "a" A) (PRINT "b" B) (PRINT "c" C))
          (SETQ #:ABORT-374 NIL))
      (DOLIST (S #:STREAM-OBJECTS-373)
        (WHEN S
          (CLOSE S :ABORT #:ABORT-374))))))
```

Here *both* stream variables and file list *are* evaluated at *run time*.

## Important

An important practical note here is that the static version is more robust in that it guarantees that all streams are closed, while the dynamic version will fail to close remaining streams if, say, the first `close` raises an exception (this *can* be fixed, but it is *not* trivial: we cannot just `ignore-errors` because they should in fact be reported, but *which* error should be reported? &c &c).

Another observation is that if your list of stream variables is not known at compile time, the code in the `body` that uses them will not be compiled correctly (the variables will be compiled with dynamic binding &c) indicated by `undefined-variable` compile-time warnings.

Basically, the dynamic version is an exercise in macrology, while the static version is what you should use in practice.

## Your specific case

If I understood your requirements correctly, you can do something like
this (untested!):

```
(defun process-A-line (line stream)
  do something with line,
  stream is an open output stream)

(defun process-file (input-file processors)
  "Read input-file line by line, calling processors,
which is a list of lists (handler destination ...):
 handler is a function like process-A-line,
 destination is a file name and the rest is open options."
  (with-open-file (inf input-file)
    (let ((proc-fd (mapcar (lambda (p)
                             (cons (first p)
                                   (apply #'open (rest p))))
                           processors))
          (abort-p t))
      (unwind-protect
           (loop for line = (read-line inf nil nil)
             while line
             do (dolist (p-f proc-fd)
                  (funcall (car p-f) line (cdr p-f)))
             finally (setq abort-p nil))
        (dolist (p-f proc-fd)
          (close (cdr p-f) :abort abort-p))))))
```

Comment: thank you @sds! Wow, how quickly you solved it! Thank you so much for help!!

Comment: Oh but macro-expanding the recursive calls step by step, i came in the last step to: `(WITH-OPEN-FILE (C "h" :DIRECTION :OUTPUT :IF-EXISTS :SUPERSEDE) 
 (WITH-OPEN-FILES (NIL NIL :DIRECTION :OUTPUT :IF-EXISTS :SUPERSEDE)
  (PRINT "a" A) (PRINT "b" B) (PRINT "c" C)))` - one has to also check whether the input-lists have the length 1 and prevent the recursive `with-open-files` call already, isn't it?

Comment: @Gwang-JinKim: that's okay: `(with-open-files (nil nil ...) ...)` expands to `progn`.

Comment: Ah true, I confused this call with `(with-open-file (nil nil ...))`. Thanks! ... hm ... I am trying my example call above ... but come to the error `CAR: *HANDLERS* is not a list` ... although *handlers* is a list ... But in my tries also with  macros ... I had such kind of errors frequently ...

Comment: `> (listp *handlers*)`
`T` strange ... why it says, that *handlers* is not a list? ... ah - I see, since it is a macro call ... I cannot place there a variable holding the input-list ...

Comment: Thank you! `(with-open-files ((out1 out2 out3) ("~/out1.lisp" "~/out2.lisp" "~/out3.lisp")  :direction :output :if-exists :append)
  (print "something1" out1)
  (print "something2" out2)
  (print "something3" out3))` worked as it should!

Comment: Oh and I learned `&key &allow-other-keys` by your example. Where did you learned about this?

Comment: I have been doing Lisp for 20+ years ;-) Please see edit - I added "dynamic" section.

Comment: Wow thank you so much! That would have been my next question how to make it possible to use it with * handlers * ... and yeah, how to do it runtime-callable ... So one could say, using a macro in a macro forbids it to be used dynamically, isn't it? - I have still to learn to "see" immediately when I have to use gensym and when not ...

Comment: @Gwang-JinKim: I suggest that you read [On Lisp](http://www.paulgraham.com/onlisp.html) for a full treatment of the macro lore. Briefly, there are two issues: "variable capture" and "multiple evaluation"; if you want, ask a separate question.

Comment: thank you! And yes, OnLisp is on my list ... Okay, I will ask a separate question.

Comment: some problems occured with the dynamic form: `(apply #'open fn op)` must be: `(apply #'open fn ,op)` (so that gensym for op is put in there and thus the arguments given in the rest of argument list of macro are put in - therefore passed to `apply #'open`

Comment: `(defparameter *paths* '("~/out1.lisp" "~/out2.lisp" "~/out3.lisp"))`
`(defparameter *handlers* '(out1 out2 out3))`
`(with-open-files (*handlers* *paths* '(:direction :output 
                                        :if-exists :append
                                        :if-does-not-exist :create))
  (print "something1" out1)
  (print "something2" out2)
  (print "something3" out3))` gives: `NO-APPLICABLE-METHOD: When calling #<STANDARD-GENERIC-FUNCTION CLOSE>
      with arguments (OUT1 :ABORT NIL), no method is applicable.`

Comment: Yes, thanks, fixed - compilation should report such bugs as warnings about undefined variables.

Comment: yes, it did warn. hm but the no-applicable-method error I try to find out - but seems difficult ... and why is there for OUT1 alread a NIL - isn't it it should be T for first streams? ...

Comment: ah ... I think ... the handlers are gensymed ... but this is a case where the handlers should be literally those called in the body ... is that the source of the problem?

Comment: basically, what you see are bugs; the can be fixed, but they do indicate that the "dynamic" way is _wrong_; you should _not_ go this way.

Comment: hm .. I would love to call the `with-open-files` like I gave in question in such a way: `(with-open-files (*handlers* *paths* '(:direction :output :if-exists :append :if-does-not-exist :create))
  (print "something1" out1)
  (print "something2" out2)
  (print "something3" out3))` with the predefined `*handlers*` and `*paths*` ... because in program I want to get the handlers and paths from lists which will be automatically created - based on how many data I have to process in the run ... - I haven't expected this problem to be so tricky :D

Comment: So all what we need is I think `*handlers*` and `*paths*` to be evaluated once in the macro body - so that the macro body processes the lists for which `*handlers*` and `*paths*` stand for ...

Comment: In case that `with-open-files` would be a function, this would be I think easy, one has to do `(apply #'with-open-files (list (list *handlers* *paths* (list :direction :output :if-exists :append :if-does-not-exist :create)) '(print "something1" out1) '(print "something2" out2) '(print "something3" out3)))` isn't it? But since `with-open-files is a macro ... how one could do that? ... maybe I should open a new question! ...

Comment: I think your problem is that you are misusing symbols (and calling them
"handlers" to boot).
I think you should create a hash table variable mapping stream "names" to paths and using that.

Comment: hm - this solution I would love to see, too - because I love to learn new stuff - especially if my old stuff is a wrong approach ... but another thing is - isn't it hat lisp is a language that could also make this possible?) - or is it always so difficult? ...

Comment: Lisp makes everything possible. However, it is still easier to write with a pen and cut with a knife, rather than vice versa. ;-)

Comment: haha - true ... however ... I mean here ... I have a main file which is to be processed line by line - but I have multiple factors by which I want to process the main file's data. So for each factor, I want to write into a separate file the result of the factor ... so I thought then for each of the file I open a `with-open-file` clause so they should be all open to process the code in the body ... the point was that I want to accelerate the processing - so that it runs very fast - it should run only once through the main file ...

Comment: Oh you fixed it! Thank you! Puh ... lisp is so different ... the macros ... brain has hard time to adapt to lisp ...

Comment: yeah ... this kind of combination of `gensym` and `let` reminds of the `once-only` macro ...

Comment: I added "Your specific case". I don't think you actually need a macro

Comment: cool thank you! I was only working with the nested `with-open-file`s because I didn't know better. I need 10 more years of lisp at least - :D . I think I understood your code and will try - if not possible today any more then tomorrow. Thank you so much for your efforts and help!!

Comment: by the way why your name is `sds` here? Are you a chemist or molecular biologist?