# Dynamic macros in common-lisp - when and how to use

Tags: dynamic, static, macros, common-lisp

In my previous question, which @sds answered very nicely,

[How to wrap and execute a lisp s-expression by another s-expression?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/53252761/how-to-wrap-and-execute-a-lisp-s-expression-by-another-s-expression/53252952?noredirect=1#comment93413719_53252952)

We came to the topic of dynamic and static macros.

The static solution of my `with-open-files` macro problem by @sds was:

```
(defmacro with-open-files ((streams file-names &rest options &key &allow-other-keys) &body body)
  (if (and streams file-names)
      `(with-open-file (,(pop streams) ,(pop file-names) ,@options)
         (with-open-files (,streams ,file-names ,@options)
           ,@body))
      `(progn ,@body)))
```

And his dynamic solution:

```
(defmacro with-open-files-d ((streams file-names &rest options &key &allow-other-keys) &body body)
  (let ((sv (gensym "STREAMS-"))
        (ab (gensym "ABORT-"))
        (op (gensym "OPTIONS-")))
    `(let ((,sv ,streams)
           (,ab t)
           (,op (list ,@options)))
       (progv ,sv (mapcar (lambda (fn) (apply #'open fn op)) ,file-names)
         (unwind-protect (multiple-value-prog1 (progn ,@body) (setq ,ab nil))
           (dolist (s ,sv)
             (when s
               (close s :abort ,ab))))))))
```

My question is: Does using a macro in a macro automatically prohibits it to be dynamic? (I guess yes ..., since the macro call in the macro definition has to be executed before compilation, isn't it? Or not?).

And when to use a static or dynamic macro solution? - Sure, if the data are only known at runtime, one would need a dynamic macro, isn't it?
What are best practices?

Comment: `DOLIST` is a macro, you're using that in the dynamic version. So obviously it doesn't prohibit it.

Comment: You should use whichever form produces the clearest code that solves the problem.

Comment: @Barmar true ... but with-open-files prohibits it ... maybe because it takes an argument which is used literally? (e.g. the stream variable?) ...

Comment: Right. You can't use a macro that requires a compile-time literal when you're calculating the value at runtime.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You misunderstood me.

When I said "static" vs "dynamic" I was talking about whether *variables* bound by the macro are known at compile time ("static") or only at run time ("dynamic").

Generally speaking, one should stick with "static" because it produces more readable code. The only situation when "dynamic" is needed is when creating a DSL ("domain-specific language").

Using "macro in macro" is a completely orthogonal issue.
One can always do that (when done correctly).

Comment: Which kind of mistakes do you know of "macro in macro" which are frequently done by beginners, then?

Comment: @Gwang-JinKim: The main mistake is debugging using execution rather than macroexpansion.

Comment: thanks! And when did you feel "you got it" - did you ever had such a moment?